# Account not supported by Bulk API request

Tags: api

We're trying to set up a bulk API connection between a BI data warehouse and our Salesforce instance. This works like a charm with all objects except the standard Account object. We're working in a Person Account environment, but want to fetch both Business Accounts and Person Account.

We're running the following command:

```
"C:\DW\Salesforce\cURL\curl.exe" -H "X-SFDC-Session: XXX" -H "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" -d @"C:\DW\Salesforce\Input\CreateJob_Account_input.xml" -k -o "C:\DW\Salesforce\Output\CreateJob_Account_output.xml" https://eu1-api.salesforce.com/services/async/25.0/job
```

With Input:

query
Account
Parallel
CSV

This returns the following output stating that 'Account' is not supported by Bulk API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload"> 
<exceptionCode>InvalidEntity</exceptionCode>
<exceptionMessage>Entity 'Account' is not supported by the Bulk API.</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

Any sugestions on how to fix would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: FYI, if you use the code formatting functionality (the button with {} or just indent with 4 spaces) the XML will render correctly as per my edit.

Comment: I just tested using the Data Loader with bulk api enabled and was able to query both person and business accounts. Have you tried testing it with the data loader first?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be that you're trying to get both types of Account in one step — you should split the operation into business accounts (i.e. where `IsPersonAccount = false`) and person accounts (where it's true), being sure to only have the relevant fields in each of the queries.

Looking through the Bulk API documentation there's nothing to suggest that the Account object is treated any differently to other objects, and it does mention using accounts in various places:

> Use the code sample in this section to create a test client
>   application that inserts a number of account records using the
>   REST-based Bulk API.
>
> J Job, Bulk API A job in the Bulk API specifies which object is being
>   processed (for example, Account, Opportunity)

Comment: We are trying to follow the recipe on http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm. But we do not get past step 2. Instead of the normal XML response, we get this response as listed above.

Filtering cannot be done until the subsequent steps (applying a WHERE-clause), so how would we distinguish between business and person accounts in step 1?

Comment: Sorry, link should be http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm

Comment: This is looking like one for Salesforce support to me!

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. Are you inserting only supported fields when inserting a person account? Certain fields in accounts are not available for person accounts. Also, are you setting the correct record type for each type of account?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm